# 2d rectangle vc-dimension shattering 5 points

Tags: classification, vc-dimension

I have seen in many places that the vc-dimension of H, an hypostases class which consists of rectangles parallel to the axis is 4.

[image]

yet when constructing this 2D constellation of points i can't                                                     seem to find any label assignment which can't be labeled by some rectangle. aka H shatters these 5 points. am i making some mistake ?

The one thing I'm not sure about is "flipping" the labels aka flipping whether whats inside the rectangle is considered 1 or -1, i believe it's the general assumption am i not correct?

[image: points comstelation]

Answer (score 1):

This set of $5$ points cannot be shattered by $\mathcal{H}$. To see that, notice that any axis-aligned rectangle that contains the $4$ points $(-0.5,-0.5)$, $(0, 1)$, $(0.5,0.5)$ and $(0,-1)$ also contains the origin which means that we cannot find a hypothesis that positively classifies only those $4$ points.

I believe your confusion stems from your second question about "flipping" the labels. The labels are just labels, so you could, in theory, change them to whatever you want **but** you have to keep them consistent throughout your analysis. Getting back to the problem, when you try to find a hypothesis that positively labels ($+1$) every point except the origin, you cannot flip the labels and consider $+1$ to mean that a point is outside.

Comment: but following the assumption that labels could not be switched. if i look at a half-space classifier i see that it cannot shatter 2 points (if we label 2 points differently we can switch what is classified above and below the decision boundary)

Comment: @TomerGigi I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: looking at the example given here by Abhishek Ghose it is clear to see that the labeling is "switched" the definition of label "above" the half space is once blue and once white. why can we say the same with rectangles?


https://www.quora.com/Explain-VC-dimension-and-shattering-in-lucid-Way

and as per your example  we can put point (0,0) in a box  and then by changeing what the labeling of "in" points we can rach all labels

Comment: @TomerGigi It's not the labeling that is switched. It's the normal vector to the hyperplane that's rotated so the halfspaces are inverted.

Comment: oh ok so in the half space case the "lable switching" is built into the definition of H while in the rectangle case it needs to be specified. i think i understand, is it trivial to say that for H' containing both cases the vc dimension will be 5? (H' containing H  above and - H) maybe it's less trivial then thanks for the answer anyways

Comment: @TomerGigi There is no "label switching" going on. It just so happens that in the case of halfspaces, the hypothesis set contains functions that "geometrically look the same" but are actually classifying points exactly opposite of each other.

Comment: @TomerGigi For a concrete example, in the case of halfspaces in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the planes with normal vectors $(0,1)$ and $(0, -1)$ visually both correspond to the x-axis (their boundary is the line $y=0$) but classify points in the exact opposite way. In the case of axis-aligned rectangles the hypothesis set doesn't have this property.